# Group processing in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

My questions revolves around applying logic in a Pandas DataFrame of the appearance below:

```
ID     yyyymm     value1     value2
1      201501     0          123
1      201502     1          113
1      201503     3          115
2      201506     0          0
2      201507     0          0
2      201508     1          115
2      201509     0          0
3      201503     0          0
3      201504     0          0
3      201505     0          0
```

What I want to do is to count the time diff for each of the IDs dependent on the consecutive order of the time value in the *yyyymm*-variable. I want to start counting at the beginning of each id and when *value1* > 0 then save the time stamp. Same with *value2*, when it goes > 0 I want to save the time stamp, ending up with table 2 below.

```
ID     time_value1   value1     time_value2     value2
1      1             1          0               123
2      2             1          2               115
```

I have a SAS background and its straightforward doing this with by group-processing.

Code for table below:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                'yyyymm':[201501,201502,201503,201506,201507,201508,201509,201503,201504,201505],
                'value1':[0,1,3,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
                'value2':[123,113,115,0,0,115,0,0,0,0]})
```

Many thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Google group by and pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will order by date, group by ID and find a row where either value1 or value2 > 0, save that row into another dataframe and move onto the next ID group. If you want more than 1 save per group ID, just remove the break

I didnt know what value you wanted in the "time_value1" or "time_value2" columns of the final dataframe, but you can easily edit that variable assignment to whatever you want

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                'yyyymm':[201501,201502,201503,201506,201507,201508,201509,201503,201504,201505],
                'value1':[0,1,3,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
                'value2':[123,113,115,0,0,115,0,0,0,0]})

final = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ID", "time_value1", "value1", "time_value2", "value2"])

def findTimes(df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row["value1"] > 0 or row["value2"] > 0:

            final.loc[index,"ID"] = row["ID"]
            final.loc[index,"time_value1"] = row["value1"]
            final.loc[index,"value1"] = row["value1"]
            final.loc[index,"time_value2"] = row["value2"]
            final.loc[index,"value2"] = row["value2"]

            break

data.sort_values("yyyymm").groupby("ID").apply(lambda x: findTimes(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the method that you are looking for is `groupby`

To do so just

do `data.grouby(['ID', 'yyyymm']).sum()`

This will group the data by `yyyymm` column and run sum on each group.

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried the groupby but it dosent help me with doing the more tricky logic of saving specific rows and getting out unique ids (the 'ID' variable in data)

Comment: Can you accept it as the correct answer? There's a tick button on the side

Comment: you can group by ID and yyymm\]